# anchor click + set img src + changing url mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the below anchor

```
<a class="images" href="/a/b/c/abc.jpg" title="@fileName">@fileName</a>
```

on click of this I am setting src of the img tag as below:

```
$("a.images").click(function () {
            var _src = $(this).attr('href');
            ("#img").attr("src", _src);
        });
```

Here the problem is upon setting the image, the url is changed to the image url i.e., localhost:1234//a/b/c/abc.jpg.
However, the url should not change, it should just display the image in a div.

can somebody advise?

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I can only select one as answer, so giving my vote to other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one mistake  `("#img").attr("src", _src)`; you have to use  `$("#img").attr("src", _src);`

```
 $("a.images").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#img").attr("src", $(this).attr('href'));
      });
```

**[e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/);** it is used to stop the default action

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) or `return false`, this will prevent the default action of the event from getting triggered.

Use

```
$("a.images").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Use it
    var _src = $(this).attr('href');
    $("#img").attr("src", _src);
    //return false; Or you can use it
});
```